The diophantine $a(a+1)b(b+1) = c(c+1)d(d+1)$

Solve the diophantine equation

$$a(a+1)b(b+1) = c(c+1)d(d+1)$$
For nonzero integers $a,b,c,d$.

Solve the diophantine equation

$$a(a+1)b(b+1) = c(c+1)d(d+1)$$
For integers $a,b,c,d$ larger than zero.

examples :
For the second question :
One solution is $a=1,b=8,c=3,d=3$ :
$$1(1+1)8(8+1) = 3(3+1)3(3+1) = 12*12 = 144$$
Another one is $a=1,b=9,c=2,d=5$ :
$$1(1+1)9(9+1) = 2(2+1)5(5+1) = 180$$

Some "motivation" for the second question.
$$1 = 1 * 1$$
$$ 1 = (\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a(a+1)})*(\sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b(b+1)})$$
$$(\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a(a+1)})*(\sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b(b+1)}) = \sum_{a_i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b_i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_i(a_i+1)b_i(b_i+1)}$$
So one wonders how dense the set $a(a+1)b(b+1)$ is within the set of integers below some $n$.
The density $\pi(n)$ is relatively easy to see about equal to
$$\pi(n) = \ln(n) \sqrt n - t(n)$$
where $t(n)$ is the number of overcounted identical numbers ; the number of solutions to
the diophantine equation
$$a(a+1)b(b+1) = c(c+1)d(d+1)$$
with distinct integer values $a,b,c,d$ between $0$ and $n$.
This seems like the multiplicative analogue of asking for the density of unique sums of 2 integer squares ($a^2 + b^2 < n$ without repetition).
And it is a diophantine based almost completely on multiplication rather than addition, what is rarely discussed.
I was unable to find references for this equation, and it did not come from a book nor homework.
How to formally solve this ?

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question may give you some idea of what works on this site, and what doesn't.

this is not homework btw

Homework or not, ya gotta follow the rules.

I find it hard to add " context " to some semi-random diophantine equation. It does not relate to anything else.

"Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc." Why are you interested in some "semi-random" diophantine equation? Why should the community be interested in it? What training or other knowledge do you have, concerning Number Theory? Those are examples of things that count as "context". Anyway, I'm satisfied, and I'm voting to reopen.

Here are a few more small solutions: $(2,14,5,6)$, $(2,15,4,8)$, $(3,20,7,9)$, $(2,20,3,14)$, $(3,21,6,11)$. I prefer to divide by four and write $${a\choose2}{b\choose2}={c\choose2}{d\choose2}$$

@GerryMyerson +1 BUT how did you find those ?

I looked at a list of triangular numbers https://oeis.org/A000217/b000217.txt and then educated trial-and-error. More: $(1,35,2,20)$, $(1,39,4,12)$, $(1,44,5,11)$.

I assume parametric solutions exist ...

Even after the reopen, I get downvotes. sometimes I do not know what you guys want ...

Maybe i should delete it ...

The downvotes are most likely in response to earlier versions, by users who haven't returned to have another look since your edits. I see why you'd want to delete, but I hope you don't.

@GerryMyerson yeah I understand "somewhat" the downvotes before the edit, but I got a downvote after the final edit and reopen, and no upvotes. Maybe diophantine equations feel to random to people. I will keep the question open, since you hope i would and since you gave a few solutions. Thanks for the support.

One of solutions is $(a,b,c,d)=(6n+2, n, 3n, 2n+1)$ where $n$ is any integer.

We have:
$ab(a+1)(b+1)=cd(c+1)(d+1)$ --- (1)
Since there are four variables we fix one variable & take $(c=1)$. We also take, $b=3a$.
We split equation (1) into two:
$13ab=16cd$  ----(2)
$16(a+1)(b+1)=13(c+1)(d+1)$  ---(3)
From above we get, $16d=39a^2$
After some algebra we get:
$123a^2-512a+80=0$
$(a-4)(123a-20)=0$  ----- (4)
hence we get, $a=4$.
since, $b=3a$, hence, $c=1$, $b=12$ & $d=39(a)^2/(16)=39$
Hence:
$(a,b,c,d)=(4,12,1,39)$
Note: We also get from equation (4) above, $(a=20/123)$ as another solution:
$(a,b,c,d)=[(20/123),(20/41),(1),(325/5043)]$
We ignore the latter solution since "OP" requested integer solution.

I am a bit confused about your method. For instance you say $c=1$ but then $c$ still occurs as a variable later on. Similarly you also say $b = 3a$ and then $b$ occurs later on. Now yeah, maybe you replace them later on, but when and how is not clear to me. $13ab = 16cd $ and $16(a+1)(b+1) = 13 (c+1)(d+1)$ seem to appear out of the blue. The solution you then arrive at already occured in the comments. Could you elaborate more on your method plz ?

@Mick. I was out of town. Hence the delay in commenting. My above method is an useful tool for getting more numerical solutions. If you notice, the comment given above by mathematician Seiji Tomita is actually a parametric solution, which you wanted all along.
